# Python nested loop optimization with function calls

Tags: python, optimization

I'm building a simple N-body integrator in python3.5, that implements the [leapfrog timestepping as a position verlet](http://young.physics.ucsc.edu/115/leapfrog.pdf).
In its essence it updates two float variables, *x_tmp* and *v_tmp* back and forth, where I need a function call to *self.forces()* to update *v_tmp*.

It is this function call that slows me down incredibly (I've profiled). The call does nothing out of the ordinary, just a few square roots and some adding and dividing numbers.

```
   for t in range(self.max_timesteps):

        #For all objects do the position verlet with generator expression / list comprehensions
        x_tmp     = [x_tmp[j] + 0.5*self.timestep*v_tmp[j] for j in range(self.num_objects)]
        v_tmp     = [v_tmp[j] + self.timestep*self.forces(x_tmp[j]) for j in range(self.num_objects)]
        x_tmp     = [x_tmp[j] + 0.5*self.timestep*v_tmp[j] for j in range(self.num_objects)]

        if(t % self.outputtime == 0):
            self.x_list[outputcounter] = x_tmp
            self.v_list[outputcounter] = v_tmp
```

and the function *self.forces()* is

```
def forces(self,x):

    r = np.sqrt((x[0])**2+(x[1])**2+(x[2])**2) # spherical radius
    R = math.hypot(x[0], x[1])   # cylindrical radius

    def _f1(r,x,y,z):
        f = -G*self.Mb/(r*(r+self.rb)**2) 
        return np.array([f*x, f*y, f*z])

    def _f2(R,x,y,z): 
        rr = math.hypot(self.disc_b,z)
        arr = (self.disc_a+rr)
        arrR = math.hypot(arr,R)
        f = -G*self.Md/ arrR**3.
        fz = f*(arr/rr)
        return np.array([f*x,f*y,fz*z])

    def _f3(r,x,y,z):
        f = -self.Vh**2/(self.rh**2+r**2)
        return np.array([f*x,f*y,f*z])

    a = _f1(r,x[0],x[1],x[2]) + _f2(R,x[0],x[1],x[2]) + _f3(r,x[0],x[1],x[2])

    return np.array((a[0], a[1], a[2]))
```

Now both lines in the upper code-block with *x_tmp = ...* in them scale well with *num_objects* (they nearly don't), but the line with *v_tmp* and the function call in it scales linearly with *num_objects*.

This is pretty bad. With *max_timestes = 10^6* I get *num_objects* seconds runtime with this code, so if I want to compute 200 objects with this code, it takes me 200 seconds. This is completely unacceptable.

However I'm a bit at a loss for what to do here, as I've already optimized a few 2D-square-roots with *math.hypot()* and a couple of other things. But the forces()-call is still incredibly slow, an occurence that would never happen in C or equivalent.

So now I'm asking for help, is there anything obvious that I have overlooked in optimizing those function calls? Or can I quickly build a C-function to call which could speed things up.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Those are tiny arrays if I am following correctly. Why are you even using `numpy.ndaarray` objects

Comment: You call the function `num_objects` time, so it makes sense that its scales linearly, or O(n) where n is `num_objects`. That being said function calls carry a lot of overhead in python and your `forces` function makes 3 additional inner function calls for each `num_objects`. You could start there for some optimization. Additionally, maybe look into NOT calling `forces` `num_objects` times if possible, by potentially passing in a larger data set, an aggregate of your data, and having `forces` break it up and handle it appropriately.

Comment: @typedefstructJames: Yeah I've tried already replacing forces() with one long formula, but that didn't help. I don't understand your last sentence, how exactly would i not call forces() num_objects times? I was thinking of building a tabulated list of values and then do an interpolation, which should be faster

Comment: For example, allowing `forces` to take a list as a parameter and passing the completed `x_tmp` as an argument, then looping inside `forces` itself.

Comment: typedef struct James is absolutely right- you should pass forces the entire list and let numpy batch the operations. You might want to look into `np.vectorize()` as well. One other note as well- precompute the `self.constant**2` values where possible as `self.constant_sqrd` or something, and pull out all those `f*x, f*y ...` into a single `(f1 + f2) * nparray`.

Comment: @typedefstructJames: Thank you, implemented that and it was in fact all pretty helpful. Speed-up by a factor of ~2. Now I'm stuck with a number of list comparisons to do the computing, but I guess there's no way around that now.